# How to Classify text based on common words

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

this question is about classification of texts based on common words, I don't know if I am approaching the problem right 
I have an excel with texts in the "Description" column and a unique ID in the "ID" column, I want to iterate through Descriptions and compare them based on percentage or frequency of common words in the text I would like to classify descriptions and give them another ID. Please see example below ....

```
    #importing pandas as pd 
    import pandas as pd 

     # creating a dataframe 
     df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['12 ', '54', '88','9'], 
    'Description': ['Staphylococcus aureus is a Gram-positive, round-shaped 
     bacterium that is a member of the Firmicutes', 'Streptococcus pneumoniae, 
    or pneumococcus, is a Gram-positive, alpha-hemolytic or beta-hemolytic', 
    'Dicyemida, also known as Rhombozoa, is a phylum of tiny parasites ','A 
    television set or television receiver, more commonly called a television, 
    TV, TV set, or telly']})
```

```
ID     Description
12  Staphylococcus aureus is a Gram-positive, round-shaped bacterium that is a member of the Firmicutes
54  Streptococcus pneumoniae, or pneumococcus, is a Gram-positive, round-shaped bacterium that is a member beta-hemolytic
88  Dicyemida, also known as Rhombozoa, is a phylum of tiny parasites
9   A television set or television receiver, more commonly called a television, TV, TV set, or telly
```

for example 12 and 54 Descriptions have more than 75% common words they 
    will have same ID. output would be like :

```
ID     Description
12  Staphylococcus aureus is a Gram-positive, round-shaped bacterium that 
is a member of the Firmicutes
12  Streptococcus pneumoniae, or pneumococcus, is a Gram-positive, round- 
shaped bacterium that is a member beta-hemolytic
88  Dicyemida, also known as Rhombozoa, is a phylum of tiny parasites
9   A television set or television receiver, more commonly called a 
television, TV, TV set, or telly
```

Here what I tried,I worked with two different dataframes Risk1 & Risk2, I'm not iterating throught rows which I need to do too :

```
import codecs
import re
import copy
import collections
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

nltk.download('stopwords')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# creating a dataframe 1
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['12 '], 
'Description': ['Staphylococcus aureus is a Gram-positive, round-shaped 
 bacterium that is a member of the Firmicutes']})
# creating a dataframe 2
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['54'], 
'Description': ['Streptococcus pneumoniae, 
or pneumococcus, is a Gram-positive, alpha-hemolytic or beta-hemolytic']})

esw = stopwords.words('english')
esw.append('would')

word_pattern = re.compile("^\w+$")

def get_text_counter(text):
    tokens = WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(PorterStemmer().stem(text))
    tokens = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), tokens))
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if re.match(word_pattern, token) and token not in esw]
return collections.Counter(tokens), len(tokens)

def make_df(counter, size):
    abs_freq = np.array([el[1] for el in counter])
    rel_freq = abs_freq / size
    index = [el[0] for el in counter]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array([abs_freq, rel_freq]).T, index=index, columns=['Absolute Frequency', 'Relative Frequency'])
    df.index.name = 'Most_Common_Words'
return df

Risk1_counter, Risk1_size = get_text_counter(Risk1)
make_df(Risk1_counter.most_common(500), Risk1_size)

Risk2_counter, Risk2_size = get_text_counter(Risk2)
make_df(Risk2_counter.most_common(500), Risk2_size)

all_counter = Risk1_counter + Risk2_counter
all_df = make_df(Risk2_counter.most_common(1000), 1)
most_common_words = all_df.index.values


df_data = []
for word in most_common_words:
    Risk1_c = Risk1_counter.get(word, 0) / Risk1_size
    Risk2_c = Risk2_counter.get(word, 0) / Risk2_size
    d = abs(Risk1_c - Risk2_c)
    df_data.append([Risk1_c, Risk2_c, d])
dist_df= pd.DataFrame(data = df_data, index=most_common_words,
                    columns=['Risk1 Relative Freq', 'Risk2 Hight Relative Freq','Relative Freq Difference'])
dist_df.index.name = 'Most Common Words'
dist_df.sort_values('Relative Freq Difference', ascending = False, inplace=True)


dist_df.head(500)
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @PV8 please see the code I added

Answer (score 2):

A better approach might be to use sentence similarity algorithms in NLP. A good starting point will be to use the Universal Sentence Embeddings from Google as shown in this [Python notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder.ipynb). There are other sentence embeddings also (e.g. infersent from Facebook) if pre-trained Google USE does not work. Another option is to use word2vec and average the vectors you get for each word in a sentence.

You want to find cosine similarity between the sentence embeddings and than relabel the category where the similarity is above some threshold like 0.8. You will have to try different similarity thresholds to get the best matching performance.